# How is it that this partial derivative is equal to 0?

Tags: calculus, probability, partial-derivative

In my probability textbook are the following equations:
$Z=X/Y$ and $X=W$.

There is a Jacobian as follows:

$$J =
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial x}{\partial z} & 
    \frac{\partial x}{\partial w} \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & 
    \frac{\partial y}{\partial w} \\[1ex]
\end{bmatrix}$$

solving for the partial derivatives (according to my textbook):

$$J =
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 
    1 \\[1ex] % <-- 1ex more space between rows of matrix
  -\frac{w}{z^2} & 
    \frac{1}{z} \\[1ex]
\end{bmatrix}$$

How is it that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = 0?$

My thinking is $X=YZ$ so $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = Y$. Where am I going wrong? All the other partial derivatives make perfect sense to me.

[image: A picture of the context]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X$  is a function of $X$ alone, and the first relation defines $Y$ as a function og $Z$ and $W$ (through $X$).

Comment: What's wrong with the equation X=YZ? Is X not a function of Y and Z?

Comment: The problem is that you are meant to regard this as a map $(x,y)\mapsto (z,w)$ or, for the inverse (which is of interest) as a map $(z,w)\mapsto (x,y)$. It isn't "wrong", it's just not what the author is writing about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of $x$ as a function of two variables $z$ and $w$. Then $x(z,w)=w$. Since $z$ doesn't appear in this expression, you have $\partial x/\partial z = 0$.

The point is to express $x$ and $y$ as functions of $z$ and $w$. Then regarding $x$ and $y$ as the dependent variables, and $z$ and $w$ as the independent variables, compute the partials $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial w}$ of $x=x(z,w)$ and of $y=y(z,w)$.

Comment: So the problem with $X=YZ$ is that it's not expressed in terms of W and Z? I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobean concerns $x,y$ as functions of $z,w.$
So the equations to work with are $x=w$ and $y=\frac{w}z.$